# Matomo track visits to different sub pages on a single page application

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, matomo

I am trying to track different sub-pages on a single page application using matomo tag manager. I have implementet the necesasy javascript code with the necesasry additions. I am tracking the movement between different sub-pages just fine.

The problem is that when i am looking at the visit log i am only able to see the last parts of the URLs and i want to be able to see the entire URL which was visited.

I see f.eks.
`/login`
`/login`
`/login`

but i have different login pages and i can only tell the difference based on what is before /login in the URL.